# Why is a thermos called a 魔法瓶?

Tags: words, kanji

I just stumbled across this word today, and was baffled to find that a thermos is a "magic bottle"? What reason is there for the kanji chosen? Was it a decision by a company who introduced/manufactured the first thermoses in Japan?

Comment: With all due respect, why is it so baffling?  It had to be a pretty amazing invention back then.

Comment: Perhaps "baffled" wasn't the right word. I found it funny and slightly confusing that the object had "magic" somehow attributed to it. I haven't seen other such examples ("magic energy" for electricity or "magic stick" for a gun or what have you), so I was wondering if there was a reason for this one.

Comment: This would help you. http://blog.livedoor.jp/blog_channel-0004/archives/27866247.html

Comment: @YuuichiTam Very interesting! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @eefara We aren't allowed to post only a link. The link seemed to help you.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Summarize the contents of the link, and provide the link for reference. That would count as a complete answer.

Comment: @YuuichiTam What psosuna said; I know you can't just post a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had not understood the reason why a thermos is called 魔法瓶, but Mr.Awazu, who was a director of 魔法瓶 memorial house, found out the reason a few years ago.

He found out a oldest newspaper article which was written the word 魔法瓶 at October 11th in 1907. The article said that in his interview about hunting, a person referred to the high performance and convenience of a thermos, which had been just imported to Japan at that time, and quoted 魔法瓶(Magic Bottle) in Aesop’s Fable. His words were used in the oldest advertisement of a thermos in Japan and he was decided to be the author of 魔法瓶.

However 魔法瓶(Magic Bottle) isn't in Aesop’s Fable and it seems to be his     misunderstanding.

This is the source. http://blog.livedoor.jp/blog_channel-0004/archives/27866247.html

Comment: Interestingly, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=MyLOAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22thermos%22%20%22magic%22&pg=RA7-PA17#v=onepage&q=%22thermos%22%20%22magic%22&f=false) is a 1914 publication of _The Ohio State University Monthly_, mentioning the Japanese term and glossing it as "magic bottle".